# JQuery SerialScroll potential plugin conflict with video player MediaElement.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, html5-video, mediaelement.js, serialscroll

I have a small issue happening that is potentially due to two plug-ins interfering.  They work together just fine with defaults out of the box.
I'm using JQuery SerialScroll to control a horizontal scrolling project and am using MediaElement.js as the HTML5 video player.

When I configure the MediaElement.js plugin though it causes the JQuery SerialScroll to function strangely, and no longer scrolls with previous and next buttons to the next or previous li as it does when not configured.

The configure code is this:

```
$('video').mediaelementplayer({
// the order of controls you want on the control bar (and other plugins below)
features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','tracks','fullscreen'],
alwaysShowControls: false,
// when this player starts, it will pause other players
pauseOtherPlayers: true
});
```

and when it's commented out, both the SerialScroll and MediaElement.js work together perfectly, but of course, i need to use some of the video players features to make it work the way I need it to.

Here are two links to show what's happening, 
The first is to show how it works when the player is NOT configured (code above commented out)

http://www.joshmeltzer.com/thesis/working_set/serialscroll_works.html

and the second is when I uncomment the code above and try to use it's implementation

http://www.joshmeltzer.com/thesis/working_set/serialscroll.html

Each page is a separate li and on the second link the scrolling moves but at very strange and variable intervals...I'm assuming the two plugins are conflicting somewhere deep??

Thanks in advance for any help.
Josh